# Another Scenario: Can monster be targeted?

Tags: descent

Inspired by this [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48333/scenario-can-monster-be-targeted), I was curious if removing one vertical column of tiles would change the result. Id est for the following configuration:

```
H░█░
░█░M
```

is the Monster (M) a valid target for a ranged Hero (H) attack through the Obstacles (█)?

My thoughts are that M is a valid target for H because a line can traced from the top right corner of H to the bottom left corner of M that merely passes through the corner (specifically not along the edge) of both obstacles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR Yes**

Please have a look at the below given sketch. The line through the upper right corner `A = (1,2)` of the ranged Hero and the bottom left corner `B = (3,0)` of the monster is described by the equation `y = -x+3`. This line doesn't intersect any of both given obstacles since for any `x < 2` the corresponding value of `y` is greater than `1` and for any `x > 2` is smaller than `1`. Hence, the solely common point is `C = (2,1)`. Since the line (quoting "Line of Sight" (page 12) from the Rules of Play)

> only touches the corner of a blocked space (without passing through the space itself ), the target space is in line of sight.

---

[image: GeoGebra scetch of corresponding configuration]